# Fake scrolling with JavaFX 8 ScrollPane

Tags: javafx-8, scenebuilder

What I'm trying to do:

- I'm trying to **render a game board** for a user using a canvas. The user
  will be able to zoom.
- Rendering the entire game board is impossible when the user is
  zoomed in as the **game board is very large**. Instead I will render what
  is onscreen every 1/30 sec.
- I would like to **create the illusion of the entire game board beings
  inside a gui like the ScrollPane** where the user can scroll with a
  mouse.
- In reality the **ScrollPane will be linked to a single canvas exactly
  the size of the viewport.**

I'm not sure what the right way to go about this is. The scroll pane does not seem to have a property that allows you to *pretend* it has a large object in it. I could place a large canvas in the scroll pane but large canvases take up memory, as my crashes have suggested. **Should I be using an AnchorPane or something? What's the proper way to do this?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like putting an AnchorPane into the ScrollPane, setting that AnchorPane to the correct size (the size of the entire gameboard) works well to let the user scroll freely. From there all you have to do is put a canvas in the AnchorPane at the right place and keep moving it (and redrawing it) makes everything work out. To make it run smoothly I think you should render 100 to 500 pixels outside of the viewport of the ScrollPane. Here's some example code from my project:

```
public class GridViewPane {
    /** ScrollPane that this grid exits in */
    private ScrollPane gridScroll;
    /** The anchor pane immediately inside of {@link #gridScroll}. The
     * dimensions of this equals the dimensions of the {@link #can} if it was to
     * render the entire grid at once */
    private Pane gridView;
    /** Exists in {@link #gridView} and is exactly the size of the viewport of
     * {@link #gridScroll} */
    private Canvas can;
    /** A label the specifies what hex is currently moused-over */
    private Label currentHexLabel;
    public void update() {
        // sets the canvas to the right size if needed
        final Bounds viewportSize = gridScroll.getBoundsInLocal();
        if (can == null || !can.getBoundsInLocal().equals(viewportSize)) {
            can = new Canvas(viewportSize.getWidth(),
                    viewportSize.getHeight());
            gc = can.getGraphicsContext2D();
        }
        // sets the anchorpane to the right size
        final double[] dim = getPixleSizeOfGrid(w.columns(), w.rows(), r);
        if (gridView == null) {
            gridView = new AnchorPane();
            gridScroll.setContent(gridView);
        }
        Bounds oldDim = gridView.getBoundsInLocal();
        if (!(oldDim.getWidth() == dim[0]
                && oldDim.getHeight() == dim[1])) {
            gridView.setPrefSize(dim[0], dim[1]);
        }
        // puts the canvas in the right position
        if (!gridView.getChildren().contains(can))
            gridView.getChildren().add(can);
        double[] x = getXScreenRange();
        double[] y = getYScreenRange();
        can.relocate(x[0], y[0]);
        // *********** Drawing Hexes ***********/

    }
}
```

Comment: It *might* (emphasized because I haven't tried it, and I may be completely wrong) be easier just to abandon the `ScrollPane` and use your own implementation: i.e. use a canvas and two `ScrollBar`s, laid out appropriately (e.g. in a `GridPane`).